# Starting a new activity and getting an odd error in android

Tags: android, android-xml, forceclose

Usually when I get an error with a new activity its because  forgot to update my android manifest, but I have so I do not know whats going on here.

```
10-12 10:38:49.762  22036-22036/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro/com.example.beerportfoliopro.Portfolio}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Error inflating class linearLayout
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Error inflating class linearLayout
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:363)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1912)
            at com.example.beerportfoliopro.Portfolio.onCreate(Portfolio.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.linearLayout
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:363)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1912)
            at com.example.beerportfoliopro.Portfolio.onCreate(Portfolio.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 10:38:49.772      480-585/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Process: com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro
10-12 10:38:49.772      480-585/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Package: com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro v17 (2.5)
10-12 10:38:49.772      480-585/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ Application Label: BeerPortfolio Pro
```

It looks like it might be a problem with my xml, for my Portfolio activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

                <!-- Card Contents go here -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/portfolioTitle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle = "bold"
                    android:text="Your Portfolio"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    >
                </TextView>




            </LinearLayout >

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

                <!-- Card Contents go here -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sortTitle"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textStyle = "bold"
                    android:text="Sorting Options:"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    >
                </TextView>

                <linearLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/portfolioSpinner"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:entries="@array/portfolio_array"

                        />


                </linearLayout>




            </LinearLayout >

        </FrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Portfolio Class:

```
package com.example.beerportfoliopro;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro.R;

import static android.widget.Toast.*;

public class Portfolio extends ActionbarMenu {



    //get beer details from bundle
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_portfolio);



    }



}
```

Comment: Try cleaning your project. "Project --> Clean...". If that doesn't help then please post the `onCreate()` of `Portfolio.java` and indicate which line is #25.

Comment: by clean do I just do a rebuild? @codeMagic

Comment: Also, you have this line in your xml, `</linearLayout>`. If that isn't a typo then you need to change it to `</LinearLayout>`

Comment: If using Eclipse, click "Project" at the top then click "Clean..." from the dropdown then run again

Comment: I just added my portfolio class code but I think the error is that typo you just pointed out. Will try it now.

Comment: If that is all of your `onCreate()` then the error is definitely not in there. If that is your actual xml then that probably is your problem. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Yea it was my typo, lol still waking up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is in the declaration of one of your `LinearLayout`s. You have

```
 <linearLayout
```

with a lowe-case "l" when it should be a capital "L". So it needs to be changed to

```
 <LinearLayout
```